# Verifying a crypto (BSC) address belongs to someone

Tags: blockchain, verification, binance-smart-chain

I am setting up a service where users will pay by sending crypto to a particular address but i need some way to verify that the user is the owner of the address they say they sent it from without it being complicated on the users end.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume the user is using Metamask, there are a variety of signature methods Metamask allows you to do to verify the user owns the address. The specific methods vary, but the basic idea is that it asks the user to sign a message with their private key for the address, and then verifies that the signature is valid. One API for this is described here:

https://medium.com/metamask/scaling-web3-with-signtypeddata-91d6efc8b290

Since Metamask supports BSC and it is generally ETH compatible, I would assume the same functions would work for a BSC address. I'm not familiar enough with every BSC wallet (such as the Trust Wallet) to know if they have similar signing features, they may. In any case, the user's wallet would need to have a feature that allows for this kind of signing for this type of verification to be done--it may not be possible if you are interacting with a user that just has a mobile light wallet with limited features for only sending/receiving.